# Is it possible to have a named angular config function?

Tags: angularjs, config

Is it possible to have a named angular config function as follows?

```
angular.module('moduleName', [...])
       .config('IsConfigNamePossibleHere', function(){
           // ...
       });
```

Comment: I don't think so. Any reason why you would want that?

Comment: Because I would like to move this configuration code to another file and then simply require it in the main angular app.js file.

Comment: no. but u can create separate function and call it from config instead of using anonymous function

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Yes that is actually what I am doing now.. however, I would like to be able to separate and then `require('configModuleName')` it in the main angular file.

Comment: actually i'm not familiar with browserify. but my best guess is make separate function `export` and call it from the main file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this. [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) can be helpful for you.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/avengers', {
            templateUrl: 'avengers.html',
            controller: 'AvengersController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                moviesPrepService: function(movieService) {
                    return movieService.getMovies();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I need to put it in another file and then `require(...)` it in the main angular file. I would then like to use browserify to be able to read it... without the need for referencing that separate config file in my html.